# attempt to index a nil value (global 'math'))

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

I am using lua to make scripts in my game,

after updating the lua libs version from 5.1 to 5.3, an error appears on the game engine every time I use 
math.X in a function

error :

```
Lua run doFile failed.attempt to index a nil value (global 'math'))
```

original code :

```
local value = math.random(1,10)
```

do you have any solutions ?

Comment: and you updated that how?

Comment: by updating the lua source .

Comment: As far as I know, from 5.1 to 5.3 the function for opening the standard libraries from C changed, so you need to update that wherever you're doing it.

Comment: and how can I update that ?

Comment: Are you calling luaL_openlibs?

Comment: is it just math or are you missing more standard libraries? please provide more information. ideally your code, if you expect any help